# Connecting docker-machine to Azure using the generic driver

Tags: azure, ssh, docker, docker-machine

I have a Docker-based deployment on Azure. I know that docker-machine has a Azure driver, which can create VMs and generate the certs, etc.. But I'd rather use the Azure tools (CLI and portal).

So I created a VM, and installed my public SSH key on it. And now I'd like to connect to it using docker-machine. I add the server, so that I can see it when I do `docker-machine ls`:

```
NAME        ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                        SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default     -        virtualbox   Stopped                                      Unknown
serv        -        generic      Running   tcp://XX.XX.XX.XX:2376             Unknown   Unable to query docker version: Unable to read TLS config: open /Users/user/.docker/machine/machines/serv/server.pem: no such file or directory
```

When I try to set the environment variables, I see this:

```
$ docker-machine env serv
Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: 
There was an error validating certificates for host "XX.XX.XX.XX:2376": 
open /Users/user/.docker/machine/machines/serv/server.pem: no such file or directory
You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs [name]'.
Be advised that this will trigger a Docker daemon restart which will stop running containers.
```

When I try to regennerate-certs, I get:

```
$ docker-machine regenerate-certs serv
Regenerate TLS machine certs?  Warning: this is irreversible. (y/n): y
Regenerating TLS certificates
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Something went wrong running an SSH command!
command : sudo hostname serv && echo "serv" | sudo tee /etc/hostname
err     : exit status 1
output  : sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I can SSH to the server fine.

What's the issue here? How can I make it work?